# updating multiple value in third table

Tags: sql, sql-server

**JobPost_Skill**

```
JobPost_Skill_ID    JobPost_ID  Skill_ID     
 -----------        -----------  -----------
      1                1             1
      2                1             2
      3                1             3
      4                2             3
      5                2             5
```

This my third table where JobPost_ID ,Skill_ID are foreign key
now i want to update query which will only update two rows of Skill_ID where JobPost_ID=1.

this means my output should be

```
JobPost_Skill_ID    JobPost_ID  Skill_ID     
 -----------        -----------  -----------
      1                1             4
      2                1             5
      3                1             3
      4                2             3
      5                2             5
```

Comment: You never showed us the other table.  What is the logic by which only two records are being updated?

Answer (score 0):

you can update using below query

```
updete JobPost_Skill 
set Skill_ID =New Skill_ID 
where JobPost_ID=JobPost_ID  
and Skill_ID = oldSkill_ID
```

**Note**: Replace

JobPost_ID the job post id you need to update

New Skill_ID  new value for skill id

oldSkill_ID  old value of skill id

**ie**

```
       updete JobPost_Skill set Skill_ID = 4 where JobPost_ID=1 and Skill_ID = 1;

        updete JobPost_Skill set Skill_ID = 5 where JobPost_ID=1 and Skill_ID = 2,
```